# i have code json code and i want to resize their textField size

Tags: html, json

textField width is too long. I want to resize it. What is syntax for that in json?

I tried to apply some html code but it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Getting started with JSON Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="deps/opt/bootstrap.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>JSON Form</h1>
<form></form>
<div id="res" class="alert"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="deps/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="deps/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="deps/opt/jsv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jsonform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').jsonForm({
        schema: {
            name: {
                type: 'string',
                title: 'Name',
                required: true
            },
            age: {
                type: 'number',
                title: 'Age'
            }
        },
        onSubmit: function (errors, values) {
            if (errors) {
                $('#res').html('<p>I beg your pardon?</p>');
            } else {
                $('#res').html('<p>Hello ' + values.name + '.' +
                    (values.age ? '<br/>You are ' + values.age + '.' : 
'') +
                    '</p>');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

in result textfield width is too long and I want to reduce it.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/jsonform/jsonform/wiki#fields-common-fieldhtmlclass and do you know how to use css classes?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to resize? You'll need to target that element with CSS to apply styles

Comment: ok learned that and modify css file.

Comment: but how to convert that json format data in jquery